# Bluetooth Packet Payload Missing in WIreshark

Tags: android, bluetooth, wireshark

I am trying to get at the Bluetooth data needed to control my Bluetooth lamp. I have created the bt_snoop file after successfully controlling my lamp through the app. I've done this many times and I always get the same result.

When I open bt_snoop in Wireshark and filter for my device all of the data has a warning: "[[Expert Info (Warning/Malformed): Length too short]". It also says "Payload: MISSING". I am able to control the light through the app, but the bt_snoop log just shows that error. I'm really lost and would really appreciate help!

Comment: You probably want to ask this on ask.wireshark.org instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.